# Objects passed as rvalue reference cause error while trying to apply decorator pattern

Tags: c++, inheritance, decorator

I am trying to learn about decorator patterns and put together the following code. When I create objects explicitly and then apply the decorators it works (e.g. `circleOne` and `circleTwo` in the code).

```
    Circle c1{5.6};
    ColoredShape cc1{c1, "green"};
    TransparentShape circleOne{cc1, 67};

    Circle c2{9.5};
    TransparentShape tc2{c2, 25};
    ColoredShape circleTwo{tc2, "yellow"};
```

However, when I create objects implicitly (`circleThree` and `circleFour`)

```
    TransparentShape circleThree{
            ColoredShape{
                    Circle{50.6},
                    "green"
            },
            67
    };

    ColoredShape circleFour{
            TransparentShape{
                    Circle{90.5},
                    25
            },
            "yellow"
    };
```

then the final object `circleFour` overwrites the data of the third object `circleThree`.

The full code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Shape {
    virtual string str() const = 0;
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    double radius;

    explicit Circle(const double radius) :
            radius{radius} {}

    void resize(const double factor) { radius *= factor; }

    string str() const override {
        return "A circle of radius " + to_string(radius);
    }
};

struct Square : Shape {
    double length;

    explicit Square(const double length) :
            length{length} {}

    void resize(const double factor) {
        length *= factor;
    }

    string str() const override {
        return "A square of side length " + to_string(length);
    }
};

struct ColoredShape : Shape {
    const Shape &shape;
    string color;

    ColoredShape(const Shape &shape, const string &color) :
            shape{shape}, color{color} {}

    //ColoredShape(Shape &&shape, const string &color) :
    //        shape{shape}, color{color} {}

    string str() const override {
        return shape.str() + " has the color " + color;
    }
};

struct TransparentShape : Shape {
    const Shape &shape;
    int transparency;

    TransparentShape(const Shape &shape, const int transparency) :
            shape(shape), transparency(transparency) {}

    //TransparentShape(Shape &&shape, const int transparency) :
    //        shape(shape), transparency(transparency) {}

    string str() const override {
        return shape.str() + " has " + to_string(transparency) +
               "% transparency";
    }
};

int main() {


    Circle c1{5.6};
    ColoredShape cc1{c1, "green"};
    TransparentShape circleOne{cc1, 67};

    Circle c2{9.5};
    TransparentShape tc2{c2, 25};
    ColoredShape circleTwo{tc2, "yellow"};

    TransparentShape circleThree{
            ColoredShape{
                    Circle{50.6},
                    "green"
            },
            67
    };

    ColoredShape circleFour{
            TransparentShape{
                    Circle{90.5},
                    25
            },
            "yellow"
    };

    cout << circleOne.str() << endl;
    cout << circleTwo.str() << endl;
    cout << circleThree.str() << endl;
    cout << circleFour.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
A circle of radius 5.600000 has the color green has 67% transparency
A circle of radius 9.500000 has 25% transparency has the color yellow
A circle of radius 90.500000 has 25% transparency has the color green has 67% transparency
A circle of radius 90.500000 has 25% transparency has the color yellow
```

As you can see the data of the third circle was replaced by the forth one and the transparency decorator was applied twice. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you code has undefined behavior because you are passing temporary object to a const ref member to your class. But when the temporary out of scope, it gets destroyed and you have a dangling reference.

Here is the code that is wrong,

```
struct ColoredShape : Shape {
    const Shape &shape;
    string color;

    ColoredShape(const Shape &shape, const string &color) :    // const ref here !!!
            shape{shape}, color{color} {}

    //ColoredShape(Shape &&shape, const string &color) :
    //        shape{shape}, color{color} {}

    string str() const override {
        return shape.str() + " has the color " + color;
    }
};




ColoredShape circleFour{
    TransparentShape{    // this is a temporary
            Circle{90.5},
            25
    },
    "yellow"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically have two options.

1. Do not decorate temporaries. The most obvious and most boring.
2. Make your decorators templated, and make them own decorated shapes, if needed:

   ```
   template<class Decorated> class Colored: Shape {
       std::string color;
       Shape;
   public:
       Colored(Shape &&shape, std::string color): shape(std::forward<Shape>(shape)), color(std::move(color)) {}
   };
   template<class Decorated> Colored(Decorated &&, std::string) -> Colored<Decorated>;
   ```

This way, if you construct

```
Colored greenCircle(Circle{1.0}, "green");
```

`greenCircle`'s type is deduced as `Colored<Circle>`, and the resulting circle is its private member, and in case you pass it an already existing object

```
Circle c{2.0};
Colored redCircle(c, "red");
```

`redCircle`'s type is `Colored<Circle &>`, so its member is but a reference to `c`.